# Magento - CMS Syntax - Layout handle update arguments

Tags: email, magento, syntax, content-management-system

When Magento calls:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

inside an email template, is the 'order=$order' bit simply an argument pair? Is it passing the entire $order object along to the phtml template file as $this->getOrder()?

I know I knew the answer to this at one point but have since forgot. =(

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the implementation of the particular directive.  In you example, the `layout` directive is handled in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
public function layoutDirective($construction)
{
    ...
}
```

The $construction parameter contains a list of the template tag's attributes.  These are parsed out into paramaters

```
$params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
```

a **new** layout object is instantiated

```
$layout = Mage::getModel('core/layout');
```

and then for each block in the new layout object, each param is assigned as a data parameter

```
foreach ($layout->getAllBlocks() as $blockName => $block) {
    /* @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        if (in_array($k, $skipParams)) {
            continue;
        }

        $block->setDataUsingMethod($k, $v);
    }
}
```

The above assumes Magento 1.7.x.

Comment: So when it passes order=$order to a phtml template, is that object all ready to go in the phtml template? Or is that dependent on the block type defined in the layout.xml file? How is $object called?

Comment: Probably quicker to just try it than for me to take a guess.

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't working when I tried initially, but it's as simple as $this->getOrder() to grab the order=$order object passed via the layout directive.